# How to initialise Crashlytics?

Tags: android, crashlytics, fabric.io

I have integrated the Crashlytics library using these steps(as I have done before without any issue)

- Download plugin from https://fabric.io/onboard/pending
- Install the plugin on Android Studio
- Follow instructions, ie allow the plugin to make changes to build.config, manifest and main activity.
- Build project and run app.

But I can not get it to initialise properly.
Either I get the error `Failed to create app with Crashlytics service.`

Or if I extend Application and initialise it in `onCreate()` using `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics())` I get `Initializing Crashlytics 2.2.2.37` but nothing happens. The plugin and web portal both don't show any progress.

I have tried reinstalling Crashlytics, reinstalling the plugin and cleaning the Project.

My project consists of multiple gradle libraries and a(apart from main) module library; in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, Crashlytics wasn't getting internet access because of an adblocker.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have setup your crashlytics with `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics())` you can force a crash to test the things with: `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();`

Once you have crashed you will start to see the data on the web dashboard.

You can also log custom data by using `Crashlytics.getInstance().core.log()`

Comment: It sometimes takes a few minutes to a couple of hours for the crash reports to appear on the system. Be patient.

Comment: Thank you. It was fixed though, my adblocker was the culprit.